# spring:batch listener issue

Tags: javabeans, spring-batch

I know this is probably a pretty simple fix but for some reason I'm not able to find anything on google.

I created a Listener that will take a jobParameter, but for some reason it's not working and I'm not sure what I need to add to my code. It says I need a ref, but what would I need to reference since everything is right there

```
    <step id="idOfJob" next="nextJob">
        <tasklet>
                <listeners>
                    <listener>
                        <beans:bean
                            class="class.class.Class"
                            scope="step">
                            <beans:property name="property" value="#{jobParameters['input']}'" />
                        </beans:bean>
                    </listener>
                </listeners>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Spring Batch's XSD, the `<listener>` element doesn't support inline bean definitions.  You need to define it as an external bean and then use a ref as follows:

```
<step id="idOfJob" next="nextJob">
    <tasklet ref="myTasklet">
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="myListener"/>
            </listeners>
    </tasklet>
</step>

<beans:bean id="myListener" class="class.class.Class" scope="step">
     <beans:property name="property" value="#{jobParameters['input']}'" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="myTasklet" class="class.class.MyTasklet"/>
```

Comment: So I made it like you did and I'm still receiving this error

      Configuration problem: The <tasklet/> element must have exactly one of: 'ref' attribute, <chunk/> element, <bean/> attribute, or <ref/> element.  Found: None.

Comment: I was basing it as an example from your code.  Your code doesn't reference the tasklet you want to run either.  Are you attempting to run a tasklet, a chunk based step, or is this an abstract step?

Comment: I'm trying to run a tasklet. 

Basically I have a listener that takes in a job parameter and puts a few values in to the jobExecutionContext that I can use later down the code.